# how to do specialize a function template when template parameter is a class template?

Tags: c++11, template-specialization, function-templates

For example

```
template<class T>
T make()
{
   return T();
}
```

and I want to specialize it when T is a class template A;

```
template<int N>
class A
{};

template<int N>
A<N> make<A<N>>()
{
   ...
};
```

Error in compilation: illegal use of explicit template arguments

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is partial specialization and is not allowed. It will be better to wrap that in a `struct`.

```
template<class T>
struct Maker
{
   T make() { return T(); }
};

template<int N>
class A
{};

template<int N>
struct Maker<A<N>>
{
   A<N> make()
   {
      return A<N>();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a partial specialization but an overload. Just remove `<A<N>>`:

```
template<int N>
A<N> make()
{
   ...
};
```

Comment: It is a partial specialization. You make a new method make<int>() which returns A<N> other than int.

Comment: @user1899020 You are using a type `<class T>` (`make<int>()`) in the first overload. Here you want it with an `int` (`make<0>()`). A partial specialization would concist of a more specialized `T` (e.g. integral type).